# Model free method for determining local structure in distances matrix

Tags: clustering, covariance-matrix

Fairly broad question, but I'm really just looking for general ideas rather than specific solutions.

I have an `N x N` diagonally symmetrical matrix where each element is between ~1 and (realistically) ~200, and N is < 150. Each element in the matrix describes how closely coupled the the `i,j` indices into that position are (bigger meaning more closely coupled). There are sub-regions within the matrix that are 'islands' of closely coupled elements. Often these local regions extend out from the diagonal, but this doesn't necessarily have to be the case.

As an example see the image below (which I just found online but does a reasonable job of demonstrating the kind of dynamic range and the extent of noise).

I'm trying to figure out a method that I can pass the matrix to and essentially identify the sets of local regions that are more/most closely coupled. The challenge is I have a few of these matrices, and the signal-to-noise regarding these local clusters is highly variable, so a defined threshold value for what 'closely coupled' means doesn't really make sense as it'll vary on a case-by-case basis.

There's also quite a bit of noise, so regularization is a bit of a challenge, i.e. one or two of the elements may be ~200 while the rest are between 1 and 50, so normalizing by the `max` doesn't really help.

I'd originally been looking into spectral decomposition and this might be the way to go, but I'm wondering if a graph-theory style approach might work well, where a fully connected network is built and then vertices are cut in either a rank-order or a semi-stochastic way.

Both analytical or numerical ideas are welcome, efficiency is not in any way a priority. Basically I'm just trying to expand my analytical toolbox so any ideas are welcome.

[image: Example image]

Comment: One small thing: by definition local structure implies some kind of model.  Is there a particular class of "models" you have in mind when you mention "model-free"?

Answer (score 1):

The islands/blocks correspond to groups of points that are similar to each other and less similar to others. So, a clustering approach might work. Many clustering algorithms can operate on similarity or dissimilarity matrices (e.g. hierarchical clustering, spectral clustering, and various graph-theoretic approaches). The details vary across algorithms, but they generally partition the data into clusters such that points within each cluster are in some sense similar to each other and/or dissimilar to others.

Answer (score 0):

Use hierarchical clustering.

You may need to transform your similarity to a distance first, though.

The basic idea is to repeatedly join the two closest objects first, until you have reached a threshold or the desired number of clusters.

It is fairly standard to use this also for optimizing the matrix representation by rearranging it with best similarity.

E.g. this image:
[image: enter link description here]